# NEON Instruction throws exception on Windows CE 7

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, arm, windows-ce, neon

I am happy to ask questions in stack overflow due to prompt reply from experts world wide:-) I wish to explain clearly the issue I am facing.

**What I wish to do?**

1. I wish to evaluate NEON instruction set through various examples available online in-order to write some algorithm on my own.
2. For evaluation purpose, I'm making use of memcpy samples available at ARM official website. Here is the link http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka13544.html.

**My Environment**

1. I am compiling NEON instruction set on Visual Studio 2008 with Platform Builder for Windows CE 7.0. Latest platform builder supports NEON instruction compilation.
2. I am running my code on OMAP3530 Mistral EVM board.
3. I have created a simple static library (NEONLIB.lib) that contains NEON instructions to perform the required operation. I have created simple Stream driver (stream_interface.dll) that uses this static library to perform memcpy operation on 1280X720X2 bytes buffer. I am loading and unloading this driver dynamically using a simple application (Neon_Test.exe).

**Issue I'm facing**

1. Once the OS boots, I am launching this application manually and following the exception I receive.

Exception 'Data Abort' (0x4): Thread-Id=047d002a(pth=c049c990), Proc-Id=00400002(pprc=8a3425e0) 'NK.EXE', VM-active=05420012(pprc=c04a1344) 'Neon_Test.exe'
PID:00400002 TID:047D002A PC=ef135120(stream_interface.dll+0x00005120) RA=ef133c18(stream_interface.dll+0x00003c18) SP=d0f3fc84, BVA=00000000

NeonMemcpy is function in my driver that calls NEON function.

**Stream_Interface.map file**

```
....
0001:000029f0       ?NeonInit@@YAHXZ           100039f0 f   Neon_Process.obj
0001:00002bb4       ?NeonMemcpy@@YAXXZ         10003bb4 f   Neon_Process.obj
0001:00002c58       NKDbgPrintfW               10003c58 f   coredll:COREDLL.dll
0001:00002c68       SetLastError               10003c68 f   coredll:COREDLL.dll
....
```

**Neon_Process.cod file**

```
.......
; 108  :    MemcpyCustom((void*)g_pOUTVirtualAddr, (void*)g_pINPVirtualAddr, 1280 * 720 * 2);

00050   e5951000     ldr         r1,[r5]
00054   e1a04000     mov         r4,r0
00058   e5950004     ldr         r0,[r5,#4]
0005c   e3a02ae1     mov         r2,#0xE1000
00060   eb000000     bl          MemcpyCustom

; 109  :    RETAILMSG(1, (L"Time for Copy using Neon %d\r\n", GetTickCount() - dwStartTime));

00064   eb000000     bl          GetTickCount
00068   e1a03000     mov         r3,r0
.......
```

**My assembly source**

```
AREA    omap_neoncoding, CODE, READONLY

EXPORT  MemcpyCustom

INCLUDE omap_neoncoding.inc

MemcpyCustom
stmfd   sp!, {r4-r12,lr}
NEONCopyPLD
PLD [r1, #0xC0]
VLDM r1!,{d0-d7}
VSTM r0!,{d0-d7}
SUBS r2,r2,#0x40
BGE NEONCopyPLD

END
```

Based on article by Bruce Eitman, http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2008/05/19/windows-ce--finding-the-cause-of-a-data-abort.aspx, the location where the exception occurs was

```
00064   eb000000     bl          GetTickCount
```

But I am sure that there is no issue in GetTickCount(), if I remove MemcpyCustom function, everything goes fine. Hope I have given all the information to help to sort out this issue. Please help me to find out the exact reason for the exception. Do i need to do any steps before calling neon functions or any other special neon instructions should be followed?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Spark

Comment: What compiler flags do you use?

Comment: Target architecture for compiler and assembler is set to default in property page of driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are pushing registers in the function's prolog:

```
stmfd   sp!, {r4-r12,lr}
```

But there is no corresponding pop at the end, and no return instruction. So the execution continues to whatever code happens to be after the function and what happens next is anyone's guess. The following, placed after the BGE should fix the problem:

```
ldmfd   sp!, {r4-r12,pc}
```

**EDIT:** By the way, since you're not actually using r4-r12 in the function, you don't need to save them. You also don't need to save d0-d7 as they're considered volatile. So you can remove `stmfd` and replace `ldmfd` by just `bx lr`.

```
MemcpyCustom
  PLD [r1, #0xC0]
  VLDM r1!,{d0-d7}
  VSTM r0!,{d0-d7}
  SUBS r2,r2,#0x40
  BGE MemcpyCustom
  BX lr
```

Comment: Exactly you are right:-) Now I understood. After completion of every function, there should be return value. I missed that in neon function that I used, right? Done, now its working without any issue. Thank You for your valuable help and guidance:-) Stack Exchange Rocks...

Comment: Ya, you are right. I don't use r4-r12 register, your hint works well. Thank you for your useful guidance and help:-)

Comment: Igor is right on this, but I think the crash is caused by VLDM even before it comes to the end of the function since with BGE, the loop iterates one more time than required.